# Munchkin Dungeon of Comprehensive Curses Technical Difficulties

Tags: munchkin

So this dungeon says any curse that affects someone happens to everyone, unless the curse already does so. Most curses are pretty cut and dry, but what does "effects everyone" technically mean?

example: What happens when I play "Curse of Generosity"? Does this only affect the player I played it on, because he gives something to everyone? Or, Does everyone have to be "generous"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretend that the curse is copied for each player and played on them.  So in your example, every player would need to be generous.  You should probably do it simultaneously so you don't have cards getting passed in a giant circle.